# pandas - how can I remove some character after find specific character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this.

```
document_group
A12J3/381
A02J3/40
B12P4/2536
C10P234/3569
```

and I would like to get like this

```
 document_group
    A12J3/38
    A02J3/40
    B12P4/25
    C10P234/35
```

I have tried to adapt a function for single string like this

```
def remove_str_start(s, start):
    return s[:start] + s[start]
```

and work with this sample

```
s='H02J3/381'
s.find('/')
remove_str_start(s,s.find('/')+2)
```

it returns 'H02J3/38', what I want to do while s is the input data frame and start is cutting the char start from the position char.

but when I tried with data frame

```
remove_str_start(df['document_group'],df['document_group'].str.find('/')+2)
```

the result returns an error

could everyone help me with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also `str.split` remove the unwanted parts and put together:

```
s = df.document_group.str.split('/')
df['document_group'] = s.str[0] + "/" + s.str[1].str[:2]
```

prints:

```
  document_group
0       A12J3/38
1       A02J3/40
2       B12P4/25
3     C10P234/35
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your help! this is also easy for me to understand :)

Comment: regex would be better though, but yeah I guess this is simpler to understand!

Comment: `regex would be better` ... actually your answer will probably outperform mine.  BTW...your answer fails if the column value does not have a `/`.

Comment: Indeed. But I assumed that the provided data in the question is mirroring the actual data at hand

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["document_group"] = df["document_group"].str.replace(r'/(\d{2})\d+$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Here is a [Python regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/snPXCu/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Comment: thank you for your help!! am going to ask how can i study the meaning of r'/(\d{2})\d+$' and how to use regex. thank you very much for your suggestion :) i will study more harder!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying too hard, just:

Create the column you want: for each value, the same value till the character where you find "/" plus 3 (because you want the / and the next 2)

```
df['new_column'] = [e[:e.find('/') + 3] for e in filt['your_initial_column']]
```

Regards,